# Azure data factory copy activity waiting for so long at Time to first byte

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I was trying to load data from on-prem to azure using ADF copy activity. By giving below query. My table is source is very large.

```
 select acid,
 mbid,
 actid,
 actdttm,
 crettm,
 rslvid,
 hsid,
 cdcflag,
 cdcts 
 from df_lake.acity
where cdcts>'2022-06-06'
```

ADF activity taking much time to load only few records from source. Below is the screen short of activity details.
I can see it is taking most of the time at time to first byte. After in seconds it is loading data.
Kindly Suggest how can I make this faster.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per [**offical doc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance-troubleshooting#performance-tuning-tips),

Check if there any throttling error on the source or if your data store is under high utilization. If so, either reduce your workloads on the data store or increase the throttling limit or available resources.

Please follow this [**reference**](https://www.sqlshack.com/copy-data-from-on-premises-data-store-to-an-azure-data-store-using-azure-data-factory/) for performance boosting and connecting the Self-hosted Integration on-premises data store to Azure Data Factory by [**Ahmad Yaseen**](https://www.sqlshack.com/author/ahmad-yaseen/).

if you are already connected to Self-hosted Integration, if so try to follow this article for [**Troubleshoot copy activity on Self-hosted IR**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance-troubleshooting#troubleshoot-copy-activity-on-self-hosted-ir)